# How do I properly populate a function by iterating over an alist?

Tags: iteration

I've defined a function that is supposed to iterate over an alist, and use the CAR and CDR of each element in the list to populate the regexp in `re-search-forward` and the replacement string in `replace-match`, respectively. Here is what I have:

```
(defun search-and-replace ()
  (let ((alist '(("regexp" "replacement-str")
                 ...)))
    (dolist (search-pair alist)
      (point-min)
      (while (re-search-forward (car search-pair) nil t)
        (replace-match (cdr search-pair))))))
```

This returns an error: `Wrong type argument: stringp, ("replacement-str")`. What am I missing?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the help. Here's what I ended up with:

```
(defun search-and-replace (alist)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (dolist (search-pair alist)
      (while (re-search-forward (car search-pair) nil t)
        (replace-match (cdr search-pair)))
      (goto-char (point-min))))
```

Where each item in `ALIST` is a cons cell of `("regexp" . "replacement-string")`.

Comment: @rjww I don't think YoungFrog was talking down to you, I see only helpful comments. Perhaps you read some sarcasm into it, but I don't think any was intended.

Comment: @YoungFrog I must have misread the tone, sorry everyone.

Comment: @rjww I guess I missed some now-deleted comments, but I confirm what npostavs said. I like reading comments that are short and go straight to the point, so I try to write them that way too ; sorry if it sounded harsh. Nothing personal of course.

Comment: @YoungFrog No it was my fault. Thanks very much for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `(cadr search-pair)`, not `(cdr search-pair)`.

Either that or use an alist whose entries are dotted pairs, with the cdrs being your replacement strings.

The error message tells you that a string was expected and instead the list `("replacement-str")` was passed.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I actually meant to include them as dotted pairs, but conveniently messed it up in both the code _and_ the example above.